# Python - How to generate permutations of size greater than the number of list elements

Tags: python, list, iteration, permutation

Sorry if that title made no sense. What I mean is this: I have a list `[A, B, C]` and I want all possible permutations of those elements that will fill a list of length 10.

```
[A, B, C] => [A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A]
          => [A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, A, B]
          ...
          => [C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C, C]
```

I've been reading through the `itertools` documentation but the `permutations` function wouldn't work in this case unless the output list length was less than or equal to 3. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are producing the *product* of the values, so use [`itertools.product()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) with a repeat set:

```
from itertools import product

for combo in product(['A', 'B', 'C'], repeat=10):
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> products = product(['A', 'B', 'C'], repeat=10)
>>> next(products)
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A')
>>> next(products)
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B')
>>> next(products)
('A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'C')
>>> from itertools import islice
>>> skip_to_end = islice(products, (3 ** 10) - 6, None)
>>> next(skip_to_end)
('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'A')
>>> next(skip_to_end)
('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'B')
>>> next(skip_to_end)
('C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C')
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. Sorry for the simple question--didn't know the terminology for that computation. Thanks very much!